# How to find request header in node.js net.createserver?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cluster-computing, reverse-proxy

I have a problem while using apache reverse proxies to handle virtualhosts for multiple applications on the same server in conjunction with node.js (I'm unable to resolve remote addresses **and** pass connections to other processes - doing either one seems to work well enough.)  This seems to come down to parsing the HTTP header `x-forwarded-for` created by the Apache reverse proxy engine.

To start, my node.js application makes use of the following packages (so avoiding additional packages is a must, this combination alone is already a house of cards)

- socket.io
- socket.io-redis
- cluster
- redis
- express

Now, for the actual issue - this code works flawlessly without a reverse proxy:

```
const server = net.createServer({pauseOnConnect: true}, function (connection) {
    console.log('Connection from ' + connection.remoteAddress.toString());
    var worker = workers[worker_index(connection.remoteAddress, worker_count)];
    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
}).listen(port, host);
```

However the `net` module doesn't parse out HTTP headers, needed to determine the `remoteAddress` for sticky sessions from behind an apache reverse proxy.

The ideal solution for this would function like:

```
const server = require('http').createServer(function (connection) {
    console.log('Connection from ' + (connection.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '127.0.0.1'));
    var worker = workers[worker_index((connection.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '127.0.0.1'), worker_count)];
    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
}).listen(port, host);
```

However it seems connections from the `http` module cannot be passed across processes as those from the `net` module can be.  A solution which allows the passing of `http`-derived connections across processes in a `cluster` would likewise be appreciated.

Just please don't suggest `sticky-session`, `sticky-session-reverse-proxy`, `socket-io-sticky-session` or anything derived from them, none work without breaking connections to either `socket.io`, `express` or in the cases of the more dated ones, `cluster`.

By the way, `workers` is populated by:

```
var workers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < worker_count; i++) {
    workers.push(cluster.fork({ 'ID': i }));
}
```

Comment: Part of the issue is that only a low level system socket can be passed across process boundaries.  You can't pass a node.js object (like an http connection object) to another process.  If memory serves me, there is the ability in the `net` module to pass the low level system socket and then have the other process rehook up a new `net` object in the new process to that low level socket.  I don't know if that's possible with `http` connection objects or not.

Comment: FYI, your question speaks of "threads", but since it looks like you're talking about the cluster module, these are separate processes, not threads.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, fixed the thread/process bit.

Comment: You can examine the source code of the `cluster` module and see how it does it.

Comment: @CoryG can you please share have you solved this (example code would be awesome) as I have exactly the same problem.